# Rails: how to escape curly braces in variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

In **home_controller.rb** my rails app has the following callback:

```
new_user.callback_url = ENV["USER_ACCOUNT_URL"]
```

In Heroku in the staging version of my app I have an environment variable:

```
USER_ID = https://staging.myapp.com/callback?user=#{user.id}
```

The app breaks and the log show the following line as the problem:

```
https://staging.myapp.com/callback?user=#7Buser.id
```

However, if I change **home_controller.rb** to:

```
new_user.callback_url = "https://staging.myapp.com/callback?user=#{user.id}"
```

...then everything works as intended, and the log shows the successful parsing:

```
https://staging.myapp.com/callback?user=100
```

How do I escape the curly braces when setting my environment variables?

Comment: show some code, how are you setting the callback url

Comment: @Subash I have added some code, and further context.

Comment: I don't understand why you are setting your `callback_url` to `ENV['USER_ID']` ?

Comment: @SUBASH yes it's poorly named, updated to something more appropriate.

Comment: Can you post your environment file and your home controller

Comment: You should only put https://staging.myapp.com/callback in the env. and add the param user=user.id in your code... it looks very bad because it's also expecting a user local variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved. I cannot have {} in separate (Heroku) server variable.